# SQL Server 2012 In-Place3 Upgrade and Timing of Database Version Change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

We are updating several SQL Server 2008R2 instances to SQL Server 2012 SP3 CU2. I know that the database versions will be changed from 100 to 110 during this process (e.g. once finished, the databases can no longer be moved back to a 2008R2 instance).

Does this change to the databases occur during the upgrade itself or the first time that the databases are brought online when the server restarts?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: Thanks Marc...will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server keeps track of version in two ways. First, your SQL Server instance has a version (for example SQL Server 2008 R2 is 10, followed by some decimals to keep track of patches).

Your databases are a separate version, known as a *Compatibility Level*. If you upgrade your instance, your databases will not be upgraded until you choose to do so. That does not mean there will not be an impact, however it does mean those databases can remain in their old version. Your example of 100 and 110 are both Compatibility Level.

Please see changing Compatibility on MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx